# How can I terminate running jobs without closing connection to the core? (currently using execnet)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, jobs, terminate

I have a cluster of computers which uses a master node to communicate with the slave nodes in the cluster.

The main problem I'm facing is using execnet is being able to kill certain jobs that are running and then having new jobs requeue on the same core that the other job just got terminated on (as I want to utilize all cores of the slave nodes at any given time).

As of now there is no way to terminate running jobs using execnet, so I figured if I could just kill the jobs manually through a bash script, say `sudo kill 12345` where 12345 is the PID of the job (obtaining the PID of each job is another thing not supported by execnet, but that's another topic), then it would terminate the job and then requeue another on the same core that was just terminated on.  It does kill the job correctly, however it closes the connection to that channel (the core; the master node communicates to each core individually) and then does not utilize that core anymore, until all jobs are done. **Is there a way to terminate a running job, without killing the connection to the core?**

Here is the script to submit jobs

```
import execnet, os, sys
import re
import socket
import numpy as np
import pickle, cPickle
from copy import deepcopy
import time
import job


def main():
    print 'execnet source files are located at:\n  {}/\n'.format(
          os.path.join(os.path.dirname(execnet.__file__))
          )

# Generate a group of gateways.
work_dir = '/home/mpiuser/pn2/'
f = 'cluster_core_info.txt'
n_start, n_end = 250000, 250008

ci = get_cluster_info(f)
group, g_labels = make_gateway_group(ci, work_dir)


mch = group.remote_exec(job)

args = range(n_start, n_end+1)  # List of parameters to compute factorial.
manage_jobs(group, mch, queue, g_labels, args)

# Close the group of gateways.
group.terminate()

def get_cluster_info(f):
    nodes, ncores = [], []
    with open(f, 'r') as fid:
        while True:
            line = fid.readline()
            if not line:
                fid.close()
                break
            line = line.strip('\n').split()
            nodes.append(line[0])
            ncores.append(int(line[1]))
    return dict( zip(nodes, ncores) )

def make_gateway_group(cluster_info, work_dir):
    ''' Generate gateways on all cores in remote nodes. '''
    print 'Gateways generated:\n'
    group = execnet.Group()
    g_labels = []
    nodes = list(cluster_info.keys())
    for node in nodes:
        for i in range(cluster_info[node]):
            group.makegateway(
                "ssh={0}//id={0}_{1}//chdir={2}".format(
                node, i, work_dir
                ))
            sys.stdout.write('  ')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            print list(group)[-1]
            # Generate a string 'node-id_core-id'.
            g_labels.append('{}_{}'.format(re.findall(r'\d+',node)[0], i))
    print ''
    return group, g_labels

def get_mch_id(g_labels, string):
    ids = [x for x in re.findall(r'\d+', string)]
    ids =  '{}_{}'.format(*ids)
    return g_labels.index(ids)

def manage_jobs(group, mch, queue, g_labels, args):
    args_ref = deepcopy(args)
    terminated_channels = 0
    active_jobs, active_args = [], []
while True:
    channel, item = queue.get()

    if item == 'terminate_channel':
        terminated_channels += 1
        print "  Gateway closed: {}".format(channel.gateway.id)
        if terminated_channels == len(mch):
            print "\nAll jobs done.\n"
            break
        continue

    if item != "ready":
        mch_id_completed = get_mch_id(g_labels, channel.gateway.id)
        depopulate_list(active_jobs, mch_id_completed, active_args)
        print "  Gateway {} channel id {} returned:".format(
              channel.gateway.id, mch_id_completed)
        print "  {}".format(item)

    if not args:
        print "\nNo more jobs to submit, sending termination request...\n"
        mch.send_each(None)
        args = 'terminate_channel'

    if args and \
       args != 'terminate_channel':
        arg = args.pop(0)
        idx = args_ref.index(arg)
        channel.send(arg)  # arg is copied by value to the remote side of
                           # channel to be executed. Maybe blocked if the
                           # sender queue is full.

        # Get the id of current channel used to submit a job,
        # this id can be used to refer mch[id] to terminate a job later.
        mch_id_active = get_mch_id(g_labels, channel.gateway.id)
        print "Job {}:  {}!  submitted to gateway {}, channel id {}".format(
              idx, arg, channel.gateway.id, mch_id_active)
        populate_list(active_jobs, mch_id_active,
                      active_args, arg)


def populate_list(jobs, job_active, args, arg_active):
    jobs.append(job_active)
    args.append(arg_active)

def depopulate_list(jobs, job_completed, args):
    i = jobs.index(job_completed)
    jobs.pop(i)
    args.pop(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and here is my job.py script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
import socket
import time
import numpy as np
import pickle, cPickle
import random
import job


def hostname():
    return socket.gethostname()

def working_dir():
    return os.getcwd()

def listdir(path):
    return os.listdir(path)

def fac(arg):
    return np.math.factorial(arg)

def dump(arg):
    path = working_dir() + '/out'
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    f_path = path + '/fac_{}.txt'.format(arg)
    t_0 = time.time()
    num = fac(arg)                                   # Main operation
    t_1 = time.time()
    cPickle.dump(num, open(f_path, "w"), protocol=2) # Main operation
    t_2 = time.time()
    duration_0 = "{:.4f}".format(t_1 - t_0)
    duration_1 = "{:.4f}".format(t_2 - t_1)
    #num2 = cPickle.load(open(f_path, "rb"))
    return '--Calculation: {} s, dumping: {} s'.format(
           duration_0, duration_1)


if __name__ == '__channelexec__':
    channel.send("ready")

    for arg in channel:
        if arg is None:
            break
        elif str(arg).isdigit():
            channel.send((
                  str(arg)+'!',
                  job.hostname(),
                  job.dump(arg)
                ))
        else:
            print 'Warnning! arg sent should be number | None'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. Use psutil library to manage the processes, find their pids etc.
And kill them. No need for involveing bash anywhere. Python covers it all.

Or, even better, program your script to terminate when master say so.
It is usually done that way.
You can even make it start another script before terminating itself if you want/need.
Or, if it is the same that you would be doing in another process, just stop the current work and start a new one in the script without terminating it at all.

And, if I may make a suggestion. Don't read your file line by line, read a whole file and then use *.splitlines(). For small files reading them in chunks just tortures the IO. You wouldn't be needing *.strip() as well. And you should remove unused imports too.